# SQL find groups based on time ranges

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table that has the following columns:

- Purchase_ID (varchar)
- User_ID (varchar)
- Purchase_time (bigint) - in UNIX

with some other less relevant ones.

There are over 60k unique purchase IDs.
all distinct User_IDs appear at least 4 times (usually a lot more) - meaning these are users that made at least 4 purchases.

What I want to do, is find groups of User_IDs, that have made purchases within similar time ranges.
For example, take User A, find all other users that have made purchases within one hour before and after each one of user A's purchases, then take these two users, repeat the process, until I reach the highest possible number of users that have made purchases together.
The amount of purchases connecting all members of the group should be no less than 3.

I realize this is kind of complex and will possibly result in many different tables, but I have no idea how to start going about this so all help would be appreciated.

Thanks to all helpers and have a pleasant day!

edit:

- as far as a data base tag goes, I am using AWS Athena, I'm not sure which functions it supports as I'm completely new to it.
- Sample Data:

> ```
> User ID   Time
> User_A    1521441850
> User_B    1521441930
> User_C    1521500000
> User_D    1521530023
> User_E    1521441900
> User_F    1521000000
> User_A    1521445850
> User_B    1521445980
> User_C    1521510000
> User_D    1521520055
> User_E    1521445100
> User_F    1521000010
> User_A    1521449850
> User_B    1521445030
> User_C    1521520000
> User_D    1521500033
> User_E    1521441910
> User_F    1521000020
> User_A    1521453850
> User_B    1521441920
> User_C    1521530000
> User_D    1521540000
> User_E    1521400000
> User_F    1521000030
> ```

- Desired Result:
  I'm Flexible on this, but essentially could be something like this:

Table 1

> ```
> Group1    Group2
> User_A    User_C
> User_B    User_D
> User_E
> ```

Table 2

> ```
> Group Name    Amount of Users Amount of Purchases Linked
> Group1        3               11
> Group2        2               8
> ```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would all help.

Comment: The answer is heavily database-specific, but it's pretty straighforward. So, two questions: 1) What's the database? 2) Can you post the indexes your table has?

Comment: The problem statement is recursive. AFAIK, Presto (which Athena is under the hood) doesn't support recursive constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Which database?

You need to know how Unix time works so you can work with it to resolve the two-hour range you are interested in.

Look up OLAP functions for your database.  If available, LAG and LEAD functions may help you.  These can be emulated with more common OLAP functions if they are not available in your implementation.